# Принятие данных на сервере и их сохранение

Tags: php

Мне надо сделать php скрипт,  который будет принимать данные(текст),а потом сохранять их на сервере.

P.S
Отправлять запрос я буду через python-скрипт.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Вы пытались сделать что-то? Покажите наработки, если да.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не знаю пхп, максимум что я делал - это гуглил, но не нашел то, что мне надо

Comment: Ладно, покажите питон скрипт, который отправляет данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо через python отправить запрос, примерно такой:

```
import requests
userdata = {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "password": "jdoe123"}
resp = requests.post('http://yourserver.de/test.php', params=userdata)
```

В PHP скрипте использовать получение данных методом `$_POST` или `$_GET`:

```
$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["firstname"]);
$lastname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["lastname"]);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_GET["password"]);
echo "firstname: $firstname lastname: $lastname password: $password";
```

Если надо заносить в БД, то используй туториалы, о том, как внести запись в базу данных. Используй [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php).